# how to mutate an array inside a v-for in vuex store?

Tags: vuex, v-for

I have a v-model inside a v-for. The v-model updates on the component but not in store/state. Im struggling to find a away round this. I have read various articles about vuex and arrays but I am struggling to apply the code to my problem. This is the first time I have really used vuex out in the wild, any help much appreciated.

**selectedPassengerCount[i]** is the part that I am trying to update

in the component I have

```
      <li v-for="(passengertype, i) in passengertypes" :key="i">
        <span>{{ passengertype.type }}</span>
        <div class="passenger-count__container">
          <button>-</button>
          <input type="number" min="1" v-model="selectedPassengerCount[i]" />
          <button>+</button>
        </div>
      </li>

  computed: {
    passengertypes() {
      return this.$store.state.passengertypes;
    },

    selectedPassengerCount: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.selectedPassengerCount;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit("updateSelectedPassengerCount", value);
      },
    },
  },
```

and in the store I have

```
  state: {
    passengertypes: [
      {
        type: "a"
      },
      {
        type: "b"
      },
      {
        type: "c"
      }
    ],
     selectedPassengerCount: []
  }

  mutations: {
   updateSelectedPassengerCount(state, selectedPassengerCount) {
      state.selectedPassengerCount = selectedPassengerCount;
    },
  },
```

Comment: I think you should add the selectedPassengerCount array to each object in the passengertypes array and find the index of  passengertypes array to update the selectedPassengerCount array accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is in the fact that `selectedPassengerCount` setter would be called only when `selectedPassengerCount` is assigned new value (array).

> The v-model updates on the component but not in store/state

I really doubt about this. Your code in fact mutates the array stored in Vuex directly (via `v-model`) without executing any mutation. You can check this by using [Strict mode](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/strict.html) - when active, your code should throw an error in console....

Way around it is to decompose `v-model`:

```html
<button @click.prevent="updatePassangerCount(i, selectedPassengerCount[i] - 1)"  :disabled="selectedPassengerCount[i] === 1"> - </button>
<input type="number" min="1" :value="selectedPassengerCount[i]" @input="updatePassangerCount(i, $event.target.value)" />
<button @click.prevent="updatePassangerCount(i, selectedPassengerCount[i] + 1)"> + </button>
```

```js
methods: {
  updatePassangerCount(index, value) {
    const newArray = [...this.selectedPassengerCount]
    newArray[index] = parseInt(value)  // value from input is always string
    this.$store.commit("updateSelectedPassengerCount", newArray); 
    // or create a new mutation with (index, value) arguments
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is working - although in the vue dev tools I have tc click on the selectedPassengerCount array to see the update.

Comment: Levy thanks so much for you help.

Can I ask you advice again. How would I tie the button increment and decrement to this as well

 <button @click.prevent="decrement">
            -
          </button>
          <input
            ref="inputPassengerCount"
            type="number"
            min="0"
            :value="selectedPassengerCount[i]"
            @input="updatePassangerCount(i, $event.target.value)"
          />
          <button @click.prevent="increment">
            +
          </button>

Comment: Wow Michal Levy, thank you so much for your help much appreciated. I was trying something similar but I wasn't quite getting it right. Just need to initialise the thing as a number somewhere and that will be it. Thanks again - legend :)

Comment: Michal Levy, Im trying something different, been at it all day, no problem if you cant help. But....... say my data was in this format. ```passengertypes: [
      {
        typePassenger: "Adult",
        count: 0
      },
      {
        typePassenger: "Child",
        count: 0
      },``` Is there a way to update the "count" so that when the number input is incremented by 1 the "count" in the state returns some thing like typePassenger: "Adult", count: 1